# Laravel 8 retrieving data from multiple models using with() returning empty arrays for related models

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-relations

I'm using laravel 8, trying to retrieve data from related models which returns empty arrays except for the parent model.
I have 4 models

1. Product (Parent)
2. Product_categories
3. Product_attributes
4. Product_photos

I'm fetching the data like this

```
$product = Product::select('name', 'description', 'price')
                          ->with(['categories' => function($query){
                                   $query->select(['category_id']);
                          }, 'attributes' => function($query){
                                   $query->select(['attribute_key',
                                                   'attribute_value']);
                          }, 'photos' => function($query){
                                   $query->select(['photo_path']);
                          }])
                          ->find($id);
return response()->json([$product]);
```

Product Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'user_id',
        'description',
        'price',
        'discount',
        'status'
    ];      

    /**
     * Get the photos of the product.
     */
    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product_photos');
    }

    /**
     * Get the attriutes of the product.
     */    
    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product_attributes');
    }

    /**
     * Get the categories of the product.
     */
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product_categories');
    }
}
```

And this is the response I'm getting

```
[
    {
        "name": "Fendi FF motif zip-up hoodie",
        "description": "sample description",
        "price": 480,
        "categories": [],
        "attributes": [],
        "photos": []
    }
]
```

Any help would be appreciable

Comment: select `product_id` from relationship table as well.  `return $query->select(['category_id','product_id']);`

Comment: @BhaumikPandhi But how does that make any difference?
Anyway I've tried it. Not working